# Computing Rare values After SMOGN - Imbalanced Regression

Tags: r, regression, class-imbalance, smote

I am dealing with a regression problem where I have the phenomenon "Imbalanced Regression". In my problem, the most relevant events are scarcely represented. In order for me to evaluate my models' predictions, I have stubmled upon this [paper](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v74/branco17a/branco17a.pdf) that deals Imbalanced Regression problem as a classification task.

The authors define a **relevance function:
Φ belongs to [0,1]** which maps the target variable domain into a scale of relevance,
where 1 corresponds to the maximal relevance and 0 to the minimum relevance.

With a relevance function defined we can determine the sets of normal and rare
values. To achieve this, the user is required to set a threshold *tR* on the relevance values.

Given this threshold we can formally define the set of rare and relevant cases, *DR*, and the
set of normal and uninteresting cases, *DN* , as follows: *DR* = { ∈ D : φ(y) ≥ tR} and
*DN* = { ∈ D : φ(y) < tR}.

The authors use an R code for computing rare values as follows:

```
 if (both) {  # we have both low and high extrs
    # see this part of the code.
    rare.low <- which(y.relev > thr.rel & y < pc$control.pts[4])
rare.high <- which(y.relev > thr.rel & y > pc$control.pts[4])
    rare.cases <- c(rare.low,rare.high)
    total <- length(rare.cases)
  } else {
    # the indexes of the cases with rare target variable values
    rare.cases <- if (pc$control.pts[2] == 1)  which(y.relev > thr.rel & y < pc$control.pts[4]) else which(y.relev > thr.rel & y > pc$control.pts[4])
    total <- length(rare.cases)

  }
```

Knowing that *y.relev* can be computed using this R [package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/UBL/versions/0.0.6/topics/phi.control) as well as this [one](https://www.rdocumentation.org/link/phi?package=UBL&version=0.0.6)

**What I want to do**

In my project, I am interested on computing the percentage of rare values after doing SMOGN (in this paper, they compute the percentage of rare values before applying SMOGN) in order to see the effect of applying SMOGN on my data. Having this said, should I:

- Define a new relevance function for the newly 'SMOGN'-ed y obtained?
- use the same relevance function as before ? (I actually tried this, but SMOGN adds some noise to the data and thus generates some new values from y, so mapping the old relevance values to the newly generated ones won't work out)